# Git Fork/Merge Conflicts?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-fork

I'm still new to version control and Github as a whole. Something's quite confusing to me and I can't seem to wrap my head around it. 
Imagine a scenario where we're two guys working on the same rails app project. Guy A has the master repo, Guy B is the one who forked the repo. Now Guy B creates a new feature that didn't exist on the app. In doing so, he had to edit, and in some cases move around, some files to get the desired result.

Meanwhile Guy A is working on a very similar feature and also has to edit and move very similar files, but with very different source codes. Or maybe he's working on a different feature that has him editing those same files, but with different source codes. Now Guy B submits a pull request and Guy A also has to merge the feature he created into the master branch. How does github reconcile these same files that have been altered in different ways by two different guys?

Comment: From what I understand, I think whatever is pushed to github will overwrite the previous commit.

Comment: The problem is, what if we want to keep both features?

Comment: I would allow the owner (A) of the master branch to push, then the other guy (B) can pull from that commit with guy A's features, then push his changes as [filename(s)]_B

Comment: So basically we'd just have to keep track of what the other is doing. Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I've worked in a multi-user project this is how the workflow goes:

- Guy A makes changes in local repo -> Push changes to remote repo
- Guy B makes changes in local repo -> Push changes to remote repo (It would fail here)
- Guy B does a `git fetch` followed by `git merge` or a `git rebase` so that his changes are merged with the changes from the remote. Guy B should immediately push these changes to the remote
- Guy A does some more changes in his local repo -> Push changes (It would fail again). He follows a similar set of steps to Guy B on merging or rebasing.

And speaking in Github terms, the concept of pushing changes to remote repo is handled as a `pull request` in github. When someone sends a pull request to some branch in some repo, it is the requester's responsibility to do the merge/rebase of his changes against this target and then send the `pull request`.

If the user receiving the pull request sees a lot of conflicts either because the requester didn't take enough pains to do the merges or because there were prior pull requests he had to take care of, which now causes conflicts, then the owner can ask the requester to send an updated `pull request` on top of the latest changes.

In other words, the person receiving the pull request would usually be happy only to accept `fast-forward merges`, but there are few minor exceptions.

Comment: Hmmmm that seems like the perfect solution. I had no idea pushing to the remote repo could fail when there are conflicts. Thanks for clearing it up, I understand perfectly well now.

Answer (score 1):

Github uses merges for pull requests. Sometimes, manual merges need to be done on Guy B's repo to resolve conflicts that pull request merges cannot handle. Sometimes rebasing may work a bit better but your mileage may vary.

Personally my method is that person that adds his/her code last is the one in charge of merging/rebasing before pushing back to authoritative repo or branch through either pull requests or manual integration.

Comment: It's a bit clearer now but I'm still a bit confused. I guess I'll understand better with time, thanks. On a totally unrelated note, what's rebasing?

Comment: Rebasing is adding someone's changes before any on your branch. For example Guy A has A->B->C->D and yours has A->B->C2->D2. Rebasing will add Guy A's commits that occured since last rebase/merge into your line so yours would look like this: A->B->C->D->C2->D2

Comment: Oh I see. I have a lot to learn. It seems the guys who created github put a lot of thought into it. Thanks for the info.